How to create Map<String, Enum> property field in Spring Boot with . and / symbols?
I have this property class:
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.prefix")
public class SomeProperties {

    private Map<String, SomeEnum> someEnumMappings;
}

and in my application.yml:
app:
  prefix:
    someEnumMappings:
      "Name-1": SOME_ENUM_1
      "Anthr. Name": SOME_ENUM_2

but I get:
Failed to bind properties under 'app.prefix' to java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.example.enums.SomeEnum>:

    Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, com.example.enums.SomeEnum>]

What can I do to prevent it?
Edit: changed to suggested code, still doesn't work. Can someone point out link to ref. doc for this?
Edit 2: changed so it reflects my problem with . and - symbols.

try "Another Name": SOME_ENUM_2

The error message is self-explanatory in this case; you’re missing the mapping for the map someEnumMappings in YAML

Found an answer. My problem was with having . (dot) in String key.
So it turns out what I need to do in this case is to enclose key in "[]".
There is link to Spring Boot ref. doc for it.

Firstly, you should add below dependency.
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

And secondly your application.yml is should be below
app:
  prefix:
    someEnumMappings:
      Name: SOME_ENUM_1
      "Another_Name": SOME_ENUM_2

You should use underscore in Another Name property.
And you should add @EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class) in main class.
DONT FORGET THESE.!

A parent key is required for the map structure (someEnumMappings)
Quotation marks should be used for keys containing spaces.
Field name in Java class must match key name in YAML

Full Code is Below.
Application.yml
spring:
  application:
    name: config-prop

app:
  prefix:
    someEnumMappings:
      Name: SOME_ENUM_1
      "Another_Name": SOME_ENUM_2

Enum
public enum SomeEnum {
    SOME_ENUM_1,
    SOME_ENUM_2
}

Logical Class
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.prefix")
@Component
public class SomeProperties {

    private Map<String, SomeEnum> someEnumMappings;

    @Bean
    public String output() {
        someEnumMappings.forEach((key, value) -> 
            System.out.println("Key: [" + key + "], Value: [" + value + "]"));
        
        SomeEnum name1 = someEnumMappings.get("Name");
        SomeEnum name2 = someEnumMappings.get("Another_Name");
        
        System.out.println("Name: " + name1);
        System.out.println("Another_Name: " + name2);
        return "";
    }
}

Main class.
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)  
public class ConfigPropApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigPropApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Output is below,
Key: [Name], Value: [SOME_ENUM_1]
Key: [Another_Name], Value: [SOME_ENUM_2]
Name: SOME_ENUM_1
Another_Name: SOME_ENUM_2


Nope, that doesn't seem to do the trick :(

Thanks, sorry for inconvenience, but I guess I left out what was the real problem when I tried to make question simpler. Posted my own answer, but your input was also on point.
